# How to change default kube-scheduler in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kube-scheduler

[This doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/) tells about how to run multiple scheduler. But I m not able to understand how does default scheduler is decided? Is it based on `--leader-elect` option?

Can I tell Kubernetes to use my-custom-scheduler as default scheduler instead of kube-scheduler?
Is there another way to specify scheduler other than  `schedulerName` in Pod/Deployment spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does default scheduler is decided? Is it based on --leader-elect
> option?

No it's not based on `--leader-elect` which is to run multiple replicated copy of the same scheduler with leader election enabled so that only one replica acts as leader at any given point in time.

> Can I tell Kubernetes to use my-custom-scheduler as default scheduler
> instead of kube-scheduler?

You don't need to change the default scheduler at the kubernetes cluster level because you can tell kubernetes to use your custom scheduler in the pod spec. An example below using `my-scheduler` instead of `default-scheduler`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-with-custom-scheduler
spec:
  schedulerName: my-scheduler
  containers:
  - name: pod-with-custom-scheduler
    image: k8s.gcr.io/pause:2.0
```

Above pod will be scheduled by `my-scheduler` instead of default kube-scheduler. If you omit the `schedulerName` then it will be scheduled by default kube-scheduler

From the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/scheduling/config/)

> By default, one profile with the scheduler name default-scheduler is
> created. This profile includes the default plugins described above.
> When declaring more than one profile, a unique scheduler name for each
> of them is required.
>
> If a Pod doesn't specify a scheduler name, kube-apiserver will set it
> to default-scheduler. Therefore, a profile with this scheduler name
> should exist to get those pods scheduled

So you could just replace the existing kube scheduler with your scheduler with name `default-scheduler`.

1. Replace the docker image of kube-scheduler with your image in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml` or
2. Edit the kube scheduler deployment and change the image

Comment: what if I want all pod/deploy to use my-scheduler. Is there another way to specify scheduler other than  `schedulerName `

Comment: You could just replace the scheduler docker image with your own scheduler docker image in static pod yaml of kube scheduler in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`. This will make your scheduler the default for any pod in the entire cluster

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I wished your answer was a little bit detailed. I also want to change the default scheduler (over all pods). You provided two high level instructions. I need the details on how to do them.

Comment: @MinaMichael you can provide schedulerName if you are using tools like, helm charts. It is not possible to give schedulerName through kubernetes cmds.

Comment: @Netro I'm using the helm chart "OpenWhisk". I wan't able to change the "schedulerName" parameter of the pods that get created.

Comment: @MinaMichael you can check this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/

Comment: @Netro Thanks for the link. I think I looked at it before. Notice that in order to make the pods use the custom scheduler `my-secheduler`, I have to edit the `schedulerName` value. The problem is that I couldn't figure out how to edit `schedulerName` in the helm chart. I couldn't find like a "template file" or something that I can work with. It seems that the pods somehow get generated on the fly. I just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: if we are using default scheduler then you wont find "schedulerName" in template file (pod, deployment, statefulset) etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't remove/replace the default scheduler in the control plane (e.g. if you are on a managed k8s platform), you can use [GateKeeper](https://open-policy-agent.github.io/gatekeeper/website/docs/) — the replacement for OPA — or another policy agent to write mutations that are applied to some or all pods on your cluster.

For example:

```
apiVersion: mutations.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
kind: Assign
metadata:
  name: pod-scheduler-name
spec:
  applyTo:
  - groups: ""
    kinds: ["Pod"]
    versions: ["v1"]

  match:
    kinds:
    - apiGroups: ["*"]
      kinds: ["Pod"]

    # Adjust this to a label that is present on the pods of your custom scheduler.
    # It's important that you leave your custom scheduler to be itself scheduled by the
    # default scheduler, as otherwise if all pods of your custom scheduler somehow get
    # terminated, they won't be able to start up again due to not being scheduled.
    labelSelector:
      matchExpressions:
      - key: app
        operator: NotIn
        values: ["my-scheduler"]

  location: "spec.schedulerName"

  # Adjust this to match the desired profile name from your scheduler's configuration.
  parameters:
    assign:
      value: my-scheduler
```

Answer (score 2):

I also needed to replace the default Kubernetes scheduler with a custom one. Here's how I did it.

I think this is the main piece of the answer. I moved (or removed) the file `etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml`. This disables (or removes) the default Kubernetes scheduler. Moreover, you can check that it gets removed by running `kubectl get po -n kube-system | grep -i scheduler` before and after removing the file.

Now that the default scheduler is disabled, I have a custom scheduler (a python script) that does the scheduling. I just run it. Here's the script below. It's not very clean, but it should work. You can tweak it as you wish. *Note that I didn't try running the script after I cleaned it. Minor errors may exist.*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import random
import json

from kubernetes import client, config, watch

config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

def get_request_time(hostname):
    # You can do some magic here.
    print("returning 1.2")
    return 1.2

def best_request_time(nodes):
    if not nodes:
        return []
    node_times = [get_request_time(hostname) for hostname in nodes]
    best_node = nodes[node_times.index(min(node_times)) + 1]
    print("Best node: " + best_node)
    return best_node


def nodes_available():
    ready_nodes = []
    for n in v1.list_node().items:
            # This loops over the nodes available. n is the node. We are trying to schedule the pod on one of those nodes.
            for status in n.status.conditions:
                if status.status == "True" and status.type == "Ready":
                    ready_nodes.append(n.metadata.name)
    return ready_nodes


def scheduler(name, node, namespace="<YOUR-NAMESPACE-HERE"): # You can use "default" as a namespace.
    target=client.V1ObjectReference()
    target.kind="Node"
    target.apiVersion="v1"
    target.name= node
    meta=client.V1ObjectMeta()
    meta.name=name
    body=client.V1Binding(target=target)
    body.metadata=meta
    return v1.create_namespaced_binding(namespace, body, _preload_content=False)

def main():
    w = watch.Watch()
    for event in w.stream(v1.list_namespaced_pod, "<YOUR-NAMESPACE-HERE>"):
        # We get an "event" whenever a pod needs to be scheduled
        if event['object'].status.phase == "Pending": # and event['object'].spec.scheduler_name == scheduler_name:
            try:
                arg2 = best_request_time(nodes_available())
                print("Scheduling " + event['object'].metadata.name)
                res = scheduler(event['object'].metadata.name, arg2)
            except client.rest.ApiException as e:
                print("exception")
                print(json.loads(e.body)['message'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @Netro Here's my reference: https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-scheduler/ but it didn't work out of the box. I had to tweak it till it became what's in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you configure the custom scheduler and make sure you disable the `--leader-elect=false` . and You can use it in pod under spec section like this

```
spec: 
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
  schedulerName: your-scheduler-name
```

Comment: what if I want all pod/deploy to use my-scheduler.? Is there another way to specify scheduler other than  `schedulerName `

Comment: @Netro so far not possible

Comment: How can this be done on Docker Desktop?